# Pandas framework: determining the count of a column data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a TSV file with data as shown below:

```
UserID    ItemID

100       1
200       1
300       2
400       3
500       2
600       4
700       4
800       5
    ...
    ...
N         X
```

I am new to the pandas framework and i want to know how can i get the count of all ItemID's associated with all the users, for the above dataset. For example, if we assume that in the above TSV file ItemID 1 repeats only two times, i need to get the count as 2 and so on. An example would be very helpful for me to get going. Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) is your friend

Comment: @EdChum can i use group by on the UserID column and get the count of the number of ItemID?

If i am supposed to use value_counts, could you please give me an example of how it can be done for the above data?

Comment: You want to get a count of ItemID for each user or the total count per item?

Comment: @EdChum Thank you for the reply, an illustration for both would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @edchum, value_count can be used on the column "ItemID". It will return a series with indices as "ItemID" and value as the count of "ItemID".

```
counter = df["ItemID"].value_counts() #df is your dataframe
print counter[1] #prints how many times 1 occurred
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information along with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 methods:

```
In [14]:
# setup data, note I have put userID 100 3 times
temp="""UserID    ItemID
100       1
100       1
100       2
400       3
500       2
600       4
700       4
800       5"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+')
# count the occurences of each user
df.groupby('UserID').count()
Out[14]:
        ItemID
UserID        
100          3
400          1
500          1
600          1
700          1
800          1
In [15]:
# count each ItemID unique values
df['ItemID'].value_counts()
Out[15]:
4    2
2    2
1    2
5    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```